# Subtitute all letters in a string

Tags: python

I have a string that was encrypted in mono-alphabetic substitution, I wanted to try and crack it using the frequency analysis of the English language (not to actually solve it, but to enrich my programming skills).

I'm currently in a situation where I have the frequencies of letter appearances in the string represented in a sorted list of `tuple`s, such as the following: `[('V', freqV), ('D', freqD)...]` (note that in this case, `V` is the letter that appears more than any other letter, so `freqV` is the largest number appearing in the `tuple`s that are in the list), and the English language's represented in the same way.

From this state, how do I substitute the letters correctly?

I've already tried the simple head-on solution of:

```
new_text = str(cipher_str)

for i in xrange(26): #26 is the length of both lists, obviously
    new_text = new_text.replace(sorted_cipher_freq[i][0], sorted_eng_freq[i][0])
```

but it won't work (one of the reasons is because sometimes the character to substitute with is identical to the decrypted one. For example `ap`=`an`, so that the letter `a` is the same when decrypted and encrypted but `p` should be `n`).

How can I go about this?

Comment: One of the problems you're going to run into with your implementation is that you're modifying a list while you're trying to iterate over it. That's going to make your substitutions go haywire because, for example, after the first few you are substituting letters that are already subbed. What you _could_ do instead, is create a mapping (read: dict) of substitutions, then iterate over the coded string, producing a new string one character at a time with the mapping.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist But that'll mess the order of the letters... So I should already give up and go with a dictionary of `{letter_in_cipher: letter_to_sub_with}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would take it and use the highest frequency and match it to the highest N frequency... something like this

```
en_freq="ETAOINSHDLUCMFYWGPBVKXQJZ" #from http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html
encoded_text =open("encrypted.txt").read().upper()#normalize to uppercase
sorted_my_frequency = Counter(encoded_text).most_frequent(len(en_freq)) #we want the 25 most frequent characters (sorted
my_frequency=join(sorted_my_frequency)[:len(en_freq)]

translation_table = string.maketrans(my_frequency,en_freq) #map our most frequent  to expected english frequencies

print encoded_text.translate(translation_table) #apply the translation_table
#note that you need a fairly large ammount of text for this to work very well ... and you will likely still need to manually translate some parts
```

note that there may be some minor errors as I did not actually run this or have any target text to decode

Answer (score 0):

Possible try doing it character by character:

```
sorted_cipher_freq = [('V', 25), ('D', 10)]
simple_cipher_freq = [letter for letter, freq in sorted_cipher_freq]

en_freq="ETAOINSHDLUCMFYWGPBVKXQJZ"

new_text = ''
for char in cipher_str:
    new_char = en_freq[simple_cipher_freq.index(char)]
    new_text += new_char

print new_text
```